# Image stops scaling after certain resolutions

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I'm trying to understand why on a webpage I'm working on the image stops scaling once it reaches a certain resolution. You'll see what I mean if you manually adjust the browser size here: http://bit.ly/1nnzqeB

Can anyone help deduce what is causing this?

Comment: Not sure - but you do have a HTML boo-boo, so maybe try fixing it (line 96-98, are not properly closed s a comment)

Answer (score 1):

Because the maximum zoom percentage is limited. In case of chrome it is 500%

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say, but it may be impossible with your current approach.

I highly recommend going for an approach without using the CSS attribute of `background` if you always want it to be 100% of the view-port width. Use an `img` tag instead. You are already using Bootstrap (by the looks of your demo). So use an `img` tag and give it the class of `img-responsive`.

[DEMO WITH BOOTSTRAP](http://jsfiddle.net/R3aqg/)

Here is an example with your image and how you could implement it into your project. If you need to place any text over the image (like in your example), just make the `div` or heading tag have a higher `z-index` with either a position `relative` or `absolute`. I can provide an example if you need it.

[DEMO WITH YOUR IMAGE](http://jsfiddle.net/cX8z5/1/)

Comment: No that's okay! This is what I need to hear. I'm losing my sanity trying to get this to work properly. I will give it a shot tonight and see what I can do.

Comment: @Dezryth - Great. Let me know if you have any luck or need any more help. If you need me to diagnose something for you, just post a fiddle :)